# Why is my hard drive slowing down halfway through a read/write benchmark?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, benchmarking

I'm using `gnome-disks` to do a benchmark on an old 5400RPM Hitachi HDD that I pulled from a PS3. It's connected to my computer through an external USB 3.0 enclosure. Here's the output graph from the benchmark:

[image: HDD benchmark results]

Why does the speed start steadily decreasing about halfway through the benchmark? I ran all the SMART self-tests and it said everything was fine, the drive is healthy. So what's wrong?

On another note, 35MB/s seems a bit slow. Don't even 5400 RPM hard drives generally run faster than that? Is it because I'm using an external USB enclosure and not connecting directly to SATA?

Comment: I *know* this is a dupe, havent looked for the live post though.  The reason the disk performance drops is that the cached data is flushed.

Answer (score 6):

That's because harddisks use "zone density recording". In plain words: there is more data on one rotation on the outside of the disk than on the inside. With a constant speed, a disk gives you more data on the outside (left side of your graph) than on the inside.

See [this excellent link.](http://www.dewassoc.com/kbase/hard_drives/hard_disk_sector_structures.htm) I quote:

> An interesting added benefit from zoned bit recording is that the raw
>   data transfer rate of the disk, also referred to as the media transfer
>   rate (a bit of a misnomer), when reading the outside cylinders is
>   considerably higher than when reading the inside ones. Although the
>   angular velocity of the platters is constant regardless of which track
>   is being read, the outer cylinders contain more data. Bear in mind
>   though that angular velocity does not necessarily compensate for the
>   fact that the outer tracks (periphery of the platter) is moving much
>   faster than the tracks at the core of the platter.
>
> Take note that constant angular velocity is not the case for all
>   drive technologies, such as older CD-ROM drives.
>
> Since data is written to the outer tracks of a drive first, hence the
>   drive is filled with data from the outside in. The fastest data
>   transfer occurs when the drive is first used and data retained in the
>   outer tracks. Many people that perform benchmarks on their systems and
>   their hard drives when new, then make some tweaks and changes to their
>   system only to return to their benchmarks weeks or months later only
>   to be unpleasantly surprised that the disk and its benchmarks are
>   getting slower. Actually, the disk has probably has not changed at
>   all, but the second benchmark may have been run on tracks closer to
>   the center of the disk. While most people that take benchmarking
>   seriously defragment their drives before running the tests,
>   fragmentation of the file system can have impact performance
>   benchmarks.

Funny sidenote: harddisks and vinyl records are played from the outside to the inside, but CD's are played from the inside to the outside. Funny world, huh?

Comment: This is also the reason to go for bigger rotating disks if possible or there is small price difference even if you don't need all that space - if you are not using up all the space you can use the faster area of your disk